# Adding a table into Word Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a table from excel into word using the following code, but I am having a slight issue when it comes to actually getting the table to paste into the document using the bookmark that I created. Instead of pasting the table that I want, the code pastes the following text highlighted in grey:

```
Bookmarks("bkChart1").Range
```

**This is the code that I am currently using:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordDocuments()

Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow As Long
Dim WordTable As Word.Table
Dim tbl, sectiontbl, positiontbl, mintbl, avtbl As Excel.Range
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range

With Sheet1

    If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Please select a template from the drop down list"
        .Range("F3").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If

    TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
    TemplName = .Range("F3").Value 'Set Template Name
    DocLoc = Sheet9.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

    'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Launch a new instance of Word
        Err.Clear
        'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'launches word application
        WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    End If

''''''''''''''''''''''insering tables'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
    'Copy Range from Excel
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name).ListObjects("tbl").Range

    'Copy Excel Table Range
    tbl.Copy
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    WordDoc.Bookmarks("SummaryTable").Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    Set WordTable = WordDoc.Tables(1)
     WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

    EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what shenanigans is going on so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW I can make that happen here if I have a one-column table and remove the table headers. Then Excel just copies a single cell and Word will paste it as plain text, not as a table.

Comment: I.e. I was wondering if that could possibly be happening in your scenario.

Comment: What I did is create a bookmark in a word document where I wanted to place the table, and then referenced that in the code using this line; WordDoc.Bookmarks("SummaryTable").Range.PasteExcelTable _                                I did not put a table into the word document. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Im not entirely sure about this line;  " Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet5.Name).ListObjects("tbl").Range " I named the table using name manager in excel and called it "tbl" would this line be able to bring that table in? would it be possible to even define a range directly in the VBA code to cut out the middle man? and if so, what should I substitute this line for?

Comment: The table I was taking about was a table created in Excel. But that doesn't explain where your greyed text is coming from (probably just the last text copied onto the clipboard). If you have a table called tbl in Excel then your code is correct. If you don't, you would see an error, but "on error resume next" is in force so you could either make use On Error Goto <somewhere> after your Err.Clear, or you could set a breakpoint on the tbl.Copyline and use the immediate window to inspect the value of tbl.Address .

Comment: If the "tbl" is the name of a table, your code should work, but in fact Word's PasteExcelTable method is for pasting a range of cells from Excel - it doesn't have to be data in an *Excel Table in the sense that Table is used in Excel today. So you could copy the cells from any Excel range (ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C3","D4") for example, and PasteExcelTable should paste that in.

Comment: So its been a while I ave tried a million and one things but I have gotten no where. However I did learn a few things, the table I am trying to copy is an array so I cant use name manager. so I replaced the code with the following to account for the dynamic range; "Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range("C2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Rows.Columns, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value.Selection"  But I am still not getting an output into word. I can manually copy the table in excel and the code works so I am assuming it is to do with copy line?

Comment: Have you copied "Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range("C2:H" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Rows.Columns, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value.Selection" correctly - it doesn't make sense to me. Also, it may help to fix the Dim statements at the top of your code - when you do "Dim a, b As Excel.Range" only b is declared as an Excel Range - a is declared as a Variant. IMO it is better to use two Dim statements on two lines or "Dim a as Excel.Range, b As Excel.Range" It's unlikely to affect what happens but it may help you trap or see an error.